# Erro ao conectar spring boot ao mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

O erro que da no spring boot é :

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2018-07-14 16:11:53.259 ERROR 13188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 01 (cria e registra categorias)
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 01 (cria e registra categorias)

Código do `aplications.proprietes`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banco
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=danilo20
```

Código do banco de dados

```
CREATE DATABASE banco;
USE banco;
CREATE TABLE categoria (
id BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO categoria(name) values("Lazer");
INSERT INTO categoria(name) values("Alimentação");
INSERT INTO categoria(name) values("SuperMercado");
INSERT INTO categoria(name) values("Academia");
```

Ja até dei um drop table , mas continua não funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com o erro, vc pode estar tendo problemas com o flyway, porém, existe algumas variantes que podem estar causando esse problema, cabe a vc analisar e verificar qual seria a mais relevante para solucionar o seu problema.

1 - É precisao adicionar essas informações no aplication.properties :

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

OBS: Essa informações são para o MariaDB .

2 - Caso o erro persista, existem algumas versões do MySql que exigem que a url seja escrita dessa forma:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/nameBase?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
```

3 - Nao esqueça que o flyway deve seguir a seguinte regra:

3.1. As migraçoes devem estar na pasta resources/db/migration

3.2. E os nomes devem seguir o padrão de 
   V01__criar_e_insere_ categoria.sql

Para verificar as suas migrações do flyway, vc pode usar o seguinte comando:

```
   mvn flyway:info
```